# NFC Write mifare ultralight EV1 IOException at format

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

I'm not able to write ndef message on Nxp Mifare Ultralight EV1 tag.

**CODE:**

```
public class WriteTagTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Context context;
    private NdefMessage message;
    private Tag tag;


    public WriteTagTask(Context context, NdefMessage message, Tag tag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.message=message;
        this.tag=tag;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        writeTag(message,tag);
        return null;
    }


    /*
    * Writes an NdefMessage to a NFC tag
    */
    public boolean writeTag(NdefMessage message, Tag tag) {
        int size = message.toByteArray().length;
        Log.i("writeTag", "size " + size);
        try {

                NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
                if (format != null) {
                    Log.i("writeTag", "NdefFormatable ");
                    try {
                        format.connect();
                        format.format(message);//IO EXCEPTION
                        Log.i("writeTag", "NdefFormatable true");
                        return true;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Error: write failed!!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following IO Exception at format.format(message);

```
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable.format

(NdefFormatable.java:132)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable.format

(NdefFormatable.java:95)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at 

com.aarfid.tickettagwriter.MainActivity.writeTag(MainActivity.java:237)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at 

com.aarfid.tickettagwriter.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:117)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at 

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1161)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents

(ActivityThread.java:2365)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents

(ActivityThread.java:2378)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent

(ActivityThread.java:2387)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600

(ActivityThread.java:145)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage

(ActivityThread.java:1314)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage

(Handler.java:102)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main

(ActivityThread.java:5136)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 

Method)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke

(Method.java:515)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit

$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main

(ZygoteInit.java:635)
07-01 10:01:18.094  14243-14243/com.aarfid.tickettagwriter W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried writing on this tag using some apps available on play store ,they also gave error in write.

> Is it possible to write on this tag using android's Ndefformatable
>   class or will I have to use ISO 14443 commands?

[image]

**EDIT**

Data : Page 2 is reserved, page 3 is OTP , Page 16,17 is configuration, page 18 is authentication password & page 19 is password acknowledge.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What output do you see on the access conditions page of NFC TagInfo? Which pages are marked as read-only? What data is on blocks 3 and 4 of your tag?

Comment: @MichaelRoland Please check my edit for page data .Thanks

Comment: What message size does `Log.i("writeTag", "size " + size);` give you?

Comment: @MichaelRoland writeTag - size gives me "size 46" as output

Comment: 46 bytes is the very upper limit for the NDEF message size. Did you try to write a smaller NDEF message (e.g. one that has at most 40 bytes)?